# Slow scipy double quadrature integration

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to obtain the function expected_W  or H that is the result of an integration:

[image: IMG]

where:

- theta is a vector with two elements: theta_0 and theta_1
- f(beta | theta) is a normal density for beta with mean theta_0  and variance theta_1
- q(epsilon)  is a normal density for epsilon with mean zero and variance sigma_epsilon (set to 1 by default).
- w(p, theta, eps, beta) is a function I take as input, so I cannot predict exactly how it looks. It will likely be non-linear, but not particularly nasty.

This is the way I implement the problem. I'm sure the wrapper functions I make are a mess, so I'd be happy to receive any help on that too.

```
from __future__ import division
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.stats import norm
import math
import numpy as np


def exp_w(w_B, sigma_eps = 1, **kwargs):
    '''
    Integrates the w_B function

    Input:
    + w_B : the function to be integrated. 
    + sigma_eps : variance of the epsilon term. Set to 1 by default
    '''

    #The integrand function gives everything under the integral:
    # w(B(p, \theta, \epsilon, \beta)) f(\beta | \theta ) q(\epsilon)
    def integrand(eps, beta, p, theta_0, theta_1, sigma_eps=sigma_eps):
        q_e = norm.pdf(eps, loc=0, scale=math.sqrt(sigma_eps))
        f_beta = norm.pdf(beta, loc=theta_0, scale=math.sqrt(theta_1))

        return w_B(p = p, 
                   theta_0 = theta_0, theta_1 = theta_1,
                   eps = eps, beta=beta)* q_e *f_beta

    #limits of integration. Using limited support for now.
    eps_inf = lambda beta : -10 # otherwise: -np.inf
    eps_sup = lambda beta : 10  # otherwise: np.inf
    beta_inf = -10
    beta_sup = 10

    def integrated_f(p, theta_0, theta_1):
        return integrate.dblquad(integrand, beta_inf, beta_sup,
            eps_inf, eps_sup,
            args = (p, theta_0, theta_1))
    # this integrated_f is the H referenced at the top of the question
    return integrated_f
```

I tested this function with a simple w function for which I know the analytic solution (this won't usually be the case).

```
def test_exp_w():
    def w_B(p, theta_0, theta_1, eps, beta):
        return 3*(p*eps + p*(theta_0 + theta_1) - beta)

    # Function that I get
    integrated = exp_w(w_B, sigma_eps = 1)

    # Function that I should get
    def exp_result(p, theta_0, theta_1):
        return 3*p*(theta_0 + theta_1) - 3*theta_0

    args = np.random.rand(3)
    d_args = {'p' : args[0], 'theta_0' : args[1], 'theta_1' : args[2]}

    if not (np.allclose(
    integrated(**d_args)[0], exp_result(**d_args)) ):
        raise Exception("Integration procedure isn't working!")
```

Hence, my implementation seems to be working, but it's very slow for my purpose. I need to repeat this process with tens or hundreds of thousands of times (this is a step in a Value function iteration. I can give more info if people think it's relevant).

With `scipy` version 0.14.0  and `numpy` version 1.8.1, this integral takes 15 seconds to compute.

Does anybody have any suggestion on how to go about this?
To start with, tt probably would help to get bounded domains of integration, but I haven't figure out how to do that or if the gaussian quadrature in SciPy takes care of it in a good way (does it use Gauss-Hermite?).

Thanks for your time.

---- Edit: adding profiling times -----

%lprun results gives that most of the time is spent in
`_distn_infraestructure.py:1529(pdf)`    and
`_continuous_distns.py:97(_norm_pdf)`
each with a whopping 83244 number calls.

Comment: Have you considered evaluating H on a grid of points and using interpolation to define an approximate H everywhere else?

Comment: @unutbu: just to be clear, your suggestion is to do the integral with dblquad like I'm doing, but move away from returning a function and instead return a list of evaluated point? That should probably save me a lot of time. Do you have any suggestion on the implementation? I would have to do a 3D grid on p, theta_0 and theta_1

Comment: Yes, (assuming H is smooth enough) you might be able to use [ndimage.map_coordinates](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates.html) for interpolation off of a regularly spaced grid, or, if you somehow know where you need to concentrate your evaluations of `H`, you could use [interpolate.griddata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) for interpolation off of an irregularly spaced grid.

Comment: @unutbu: you're the wind beneath my wings. In fact p needs to be positive and I have some ideas of what theta_1 and theta_0 should be, so I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: @cd98 I have a similar issue. Did you solve your problem with [@unutbu suggestion of using `interpolate.griddata`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253020/slow-scipy-double-quadrature-integration#comment39345726_25253020)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

The time taken to integrate your function sounds very long if the function is not a nasty one.

First thing I suggest you do is to profile where the time is spent. Is it spent in `dblquad` or elsewhere? How many calls are made to `w_B` during the integration? If the time is spent in `dblquad` and the number of calls is very high, could you use looser tolerances in the integration?

It seems that the multiplication by the gaussians actually enables you to limit the integration limits a great deal, as most of the energy of the gaussian is within a very small area. You might want to try and calculate reasonable tighter bounds. You have already limited the area into -10..10; is there any significant performance change between -100..100, -10..10, and -1..1?

---

If you know your functions are relatively smooth, then there is a Mickey-Mouse version of the integration:

- determine reasonable upper and lower limits in both axes (by the gaussians)
- calculate a reasonable grid density (e.g. 100 points in each direction)
- calculate the w_B for each of these points (and this will be much faster, if it is possible to require a vectorized version of w_B)
- sum it all together

This is very low-tech but also very fast. Whether or not it gives you results which are good enough for the outer iteration is an interesting question. It just might.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I added some results from %prun. It seems the issue is that it's calculating the normal pdf too many times, so maybe decreasing tolerance and bounds might work (I'll try it and report). I think making some sort of exp(log) transformation on epsilon and beta would help the bounding issue, but I haven't figured out how to yet.

Comment: You probably also checked that a lot of time is spent in the pdf calculation (not only number of calls). You might try to replace the Gaussians by a home-brewn version (it is only one exp, one square, one subtraction, one division, cannot take much time).